# Как удалить повторяющиеся символы из двух строк?

Tags: java, строки

Есть две строки, `str1 = "hello"` и `str2 = "ht"`. Можно ли удалить совпадающие символы `str2` из `str1`, чтобы в `str1` осталось `"ello"`?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, взять каждый символ из второй строки и удалить его из первой

```
var str1  = "hello"
var str2  = "hl"

for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    str1 = str1.replaceAll(str2[i], '');
}
// или
str2.split('').forEach(el => str1 = str1.replaceAll(el, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "hello";
String str2 = "ht";
str1 = str1.replaceAll("[" + Pattern.quote(str2) + "]","");
```

Comment: Чтобы не просочились спецсимволы, не помешает обернуть в quote(): `replaceAll("[" + Pattern.quote(str2) + "]", "")`.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил!